# What triggers the servletResponse for it to send the data/file to the client

Tags: servlets, grails

I am working on an app that creates a report and sends it to the client. I used the following : XDocReport, Grails.

Here's my code:

```
   def OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    try {

        def InputStream inn = new FileInputStream(new File(invoiceExporterService.getTemplatePath(templateName)));
        def IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(inn, TemplateEngineKind.Freemarker);
        def FieldsMetadata metadata = report.createFieldsMetadata();
        metadata.load("invoiceDetails", CustomerInvoiceDetail.class, true);

        IContext context = report.createContext();
        context = invoiceExporterService.prepareDataForExport(context, id);
        report.process(context, outputStream);


    } catch (IOException io) {

        println "**" + io.properties + "**"
        return false;
    } catch (XDocReportException xd) {

        println "**" + xd.properties + "**"
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        println  "**" + e.properties + "**"
        return false;
    }


    def String fileName = DataFormatUtil.formatFileName(invoiceExporterService.getOutputFilename(), "docx");
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
```

//        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        println fileName
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=${fileName}");
        outputStream.flush();

Now the problem is, it doesn't send the file to the client. It is sending something else which is not the file that I need.

My questions are:

1) given the code above, what is wrong? What is the cause of the bug?
2) What is the trigger or line of code that needs to be executed so that the file will be sent to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, I was able to make my code work by setting content-type and disposition type before this line :

```
def OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
```

But still, the question remains. What is  the trigger/line of code that needs to be executed for servletResponse to send the data to the client?